# Searching for error codes with regex pattern in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to search my logs within the search bar of Kibana UI for error codes that consist of:

- a fixed 3 digit String
- a minus
- a 5 digit number

, e.g. `TED-12345`. The error codes can be located anywhere inside the message field

I tried the following Regex `message: /.*TED-[0-9]{5}.*/` but it did not return the expected results. I probably mixed query and "search bar syntax". Can anybody suggest the correct regex?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have the Lucene syntax enabled for your queries, because Kibana Query Language does not support regular expressions.

From docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/kuery-query.html

> KQL has a different set of features than the Lucene query syntax. KQL is able to query nested fields and scripted fields. KQL does not support regular expressions or searching with fuzzy terms. To use the legacy Lucene syntax, click KQL next to the Search field, and then turn off KQL.